# Eloquent model method or attribute for calculation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm looking for a way to define a custom Eloquent method which only returns a calculation based on several columns in the according database table. I also tried setting it in the models attributes, but neither seem to work. Maybe I'm missing something, here's what I got so far:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Team extends Model
{
    public function difference() {
        return $this->goals_f - $this->goals_a;
    }
}
```

The error message I'm recieving is:

```
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
```

Comment: Please include your laravel version! Is this 5.2?

Comment: @OzanKurt I don't think the version is the issue here. It depends what `$this` is in the function. If it's an instance of Eloquent's query building, it expects a certain return type (Relationship), but if `$this` is an instance of `Team` this function should work correctly. Or at least I'm pretty sure that's the issue.

Comment: That error has been removed from Laravel 5.2. :)

Comment: @OzanKurt Oh really? Guess I missed that. Good to know! (OP) Could you provide the context of this issue? What I mean by that is where you call this `->difference()` function. That will help debug this further.

Comment: @OzanKurt, I just ran a test on a laravel 5.2 installation and that error definitely occurs when you call a method as if it was a property.

Comment: Yep, but you can still return some other stuff :)

Comment: I am using Laravel Framework version 5.1.28 (LTS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error makes it sound to me like you are trying to call your method like a property" `$team->difference`. You would instead need to call it like: `$team->difference()`. If you want to get the difference as if it was a property, then you would need to define an accessor:

```
public function getDifferenceAttribute(){
    return $this->goals_f - $this->goals_a;
}
```

Then you could call it like `$team->difference`.

You could also define a protected `$appends` property to your model so that the difference property is subsequently visible in it's JSON representation:

```
protected $appends = ['difference'];
```

More information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: It might not be Laravel 5.2, there will not be any errors if he were to use 5.2.